# How to merge multiple .cs files into single .dll?

Tags: c#, dll

I am converting multiple .IL files into .cs, Now I want to create a single c# project with these .cs files. And then i want a .dll file for this project.

I have already created a c# project. I created a folder "Application" into this project. Now I am moving all the .cs files into this folder. After compiling this c# project i am getting its .dll file into bin folder.

Is this steps correct?

Comment: It is very difficult to make sense of this question. You turn multiple .cs files into a single .dll using a *compiler*. The C# compiler will do this for you. You put all the .cs files into a project, and then compile it to a .dll.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Nuget Package Costura.Fody for it.

It merges everything into the target .exe, but maybe as Class Project it merges everything into one DLL?

You should give it a try:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/

Answer (score 0):

The steps are correct as long as the result satisfies the initial task.

What you described sounds legitimate. Now it's your turn to check if the dll works as intended.